How to fix my luarocks installation, on Windows?
I'm just starting with Lua. I have the newest pre-build lua 5.4 binaries for Windows, and the newest pre-built luarocks binaries for Windows, both from the "original sites", but luarocks just won't work. Neither with my lua54 install, nor with the lua 5.1 with which it is delivered. I tried both as a normal user, and as an Administrator, with the same result. The luarocks installation does not seem to itself copy it's own lua version anywhere, so I copied it myself, and edited "luarocks.bat" to use it.
C:\Windows\system32>luarocks
C:\Lua\lua54.exe: C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\core\util.lua:18: attempt to concatenate a nil value
stack traceback:
        C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\core\util.lua:18: in function 'luarocks.util.popen_read'
        C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\util.lua:420: in function 'luarocks.util.check_lua_version'
        C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\util.lua:491: in upvalue 'find_lua_bindir'
        C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\util.lua:512: in function 'luarocks.util.find_lua'
        (...tail calls...)
        C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\cmd.lua:633: in function 'luarocks.cmd.run_command'
        C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\luarocks.lua:35: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

C:\Windows\system32>luarocks
C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\win32\lua5.1\bin\lua5.1.exe: ...gram Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\core\util.lua:18: attempt to concatenate a nil value
stack traceback:
        ...gram Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\core\util.lua:18: in function 'popen_read'
        ...:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\util.lua:420: in function 'check_lua_version'
        ...:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\util.lua:491: in function 'find_lua_bindir'
        ...:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\util.lua:512: in function <...:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\util.lua:510>
        (tail call): ?
        C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\cmd.lua:633: in function 'run_command'
        C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\luarocks.lua:35: in main chunk
        [C]: ?


Well, it wasn't so hard. I opened "util.lua", and the problem was clear: The "TMP" environment variable was not defined anymore. I can't count anymore, how many times I defined this. I hate Windows sometimes ...
